# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env/jdbc/DataSource on JBOSS with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, jdbc, jboss

The JNDI name in my domain.xml is

The Context.lookup has been defined as follows:

```
dsName = "java:comp/env";

Context ctx = (Context) new javax.naming.InitialContext();

Context envCtx = (Context)ctx.lookup(dsName);

DataSource ds = (DataSource)envCtx.lookup("jdbc/DataSource");

conn = ds.getConnection();
```

I'm getting the following exception when connected to SQLserver with the following configuration where as it is working fine with Oracle.The lookup name somehow is not validated properly and connection object is getting null.

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env/jdbc/DataSource
>
> ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78)  at
> org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:104)
>
> ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78)  at
> org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:197)
> java.lang.NullPointerException

Even Tried with something like

```
DataSource ds = (DataSource)envCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/DataSource");
```

Could anyone suggest on this.

Thanks

Comment: Hello, did you find the solution? I am having the similar issue

Answer (score 1):

Check the logs and/or the JNDI tree in the administration console.

Try these:

```
"java:DataSource"
"java:jboss/datasources/DataSource"
```

If not, please paste here the data source config section in the config file (e.g. standalone.xml)